# Why is my translations not working with react-i18next?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-i18next

This is my config file:

i18n.js:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const fallbc = ['en'];
const langArr = ['en', 'de'];

i18n
    .use(detector)
    .use(Backend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/register/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        fallck,
        debug: true,
        whitelist: langArr,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

And when I try this:

```
import i18n from '../i18n';

return (
         <div>
           <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('de')}>de</button>
           <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('en')}>en</button>
         </div>
       );
```

Only English is rendered, the German is not. What am I doing wrong?

Is something wrong with my configuration? I feel that I am really close to resolving this.

Answer (score 3):

`i18n.Init` is a lazy load function You have to wait for `callback` has to be called. Else use SyncBackend. Else start app lazy.

**Sample:**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import SyncBackend from 'i18next-sync-fs-backend';


// working
i18next
  .use(SyncBackend)
  .init({ initImmediate: false });

i18next.t('key'); // -> will return value
```

**Lazy Start:**

```
export default (callback) => {
const instance = i18n
    .use(detector)
    .use(Backend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/register/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        fallck,
        debug: true,
        whitelist: langArr,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    },() => callback(instance));
};

import i18nInit from '../i18n';

i18nInit((i18n) =>{
// lazy start here
return (
         <div>
           <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('de')}>de</button>
           <button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('en')}>en</button>
         </div>
       );

})
```

**More:** https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

Comment: Thans. Is there a better way to make use of what I have?

Comment: You can use `react.i18next` module.https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide

Comment: Why is that not recommended? How can we then use `i18next-xhr-backend` package for this?

Comment: Please check document for more info. I just guided what is the issue.

Comment: Ok one more question, when you say "Else start app lazy." - please provide example...

Comment: OK, why is that not recommended?

Comment: I am asking about your code, that you put that it is not recommended using callback. Why not?

Comment: I mean if u can handle all fail case than ok, But not recommend from my side to write using callback. Else u can use it.

Comment: Please use callback, if u dont have better solution.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`